# Azure DevOpsでゴミ箱に移動したリポジトリの生存期間

Tags: git, azure, rest

AzureDevOpsで削除したリポジトリを復元する方法を検索していると下記のページに行きつきました

[Repositories - Restore Repository From Recycle Bin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/restore%20repository%20from%20recycle%20bin?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

このページの冒頭にある以下の文章の「Recently」はどれくらいの期間になりますでしょうか

> Recover a soft-deleted Git repository. Recently deleted repositories go into a soft-delete state for a period of time before they are hard deleted and become unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

興味があったので、サポートに聞いてみました。現在の仕様では30日です。ドキュメントに書いていないのは将来変更するかもしれないから、だそうです。